# Pivoting Columns still creates repeating values

Tags: sql

So i have done a sql query where I made a table which is created from another table but some dynamic pivoting action is written in to the query to allow better looking data for my ssrs reports. So below are the examples of what I am speaking of. As you can see, my before pivot has many more columns but after pivoting I am only using Day, PRojectName and Val. However as you can see, 2015-09-10 shows up twice at the end of the table. what can i do to fix this issue. [image: Main table queries are generating data off of]

[image: Another table for joining]

[image: Before Pivot]

[image: After Pivot(the last two rows display the problem.]

Comment: Try `Select Cast (day as date) day`  in your pivot to remove the possibility of millisecond difference in your date column. Also pasting in the text will make it much more likely that you will get help

Comment: I have already tried casting and converting Day into different formats. The time should not matter because in all of my tables, the time stays at '12:00:00'

Comment: they're for 2 different projects, bereavement and vacation?  or is it because one day has values in the 'general' pivoted column and the other in the 'training' column?  If so, you might need to group your pivoted result by day and get the max() value for each column.

Comment: So I tried putting Group by day after (...pvttable') but it gives me error on having no clause for the group by statment. However I am already doing a sum(val) in my query which if I understand correctly should already add up the val in the day if it matches the project name.

Comment: Can't you just SUM then in the report?

Comment: The report already does the summing with its function SUM(..) which will sum up all the values in the columns on the right of Day. But I want the dataset to only have distinct values. This should be a easy fix but For some reason it just wont go away.